# Cannot create DataStream inside a flatMap() function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to create a DataStream inside a flatMap function. However I when I run `dataStream.print()`, it shows nothing. Here is my code:

```
public class test {

    static StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String s = "test message";

        DataStream<String> data = env.fromElements(s);
        data.flatMap(new customFlatMap()).print();

        env.execute();
    }

    private static class customFlatMap extends RichFlatMapFunction<String, String> {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String s, Collector<String> collector) {
            DataStream<String> newStream = env.fromElements(s);
            System.out.println("-----");
            newStream.print();
            System.out.println("-----");

            collector.collect(s);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my code, it prints the following result:

```
-----
-----
8> test message
```

Nothing shows between two dashes.

Can someone help me explain this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You can't really "create a new stream" within an existing operator. The Flink jobs run from a streaming environment and you can think of it as a chain that continually forwards operators to other operators. If you need a given point to produce more output, you can always use the `collector.collect()` call to send more elements downstream. Any additional details that you could provide would help us guide you to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Rion. Thank you for your response. I'm trying to consume messages from a Kafka topic, process them and write into Hbase. And during processing, I need to send some of them to another Kafka topic for further processing. The [doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#kafka-sink) I read shows that I need to create a DataStream to KafkaSink, that's why I want to create a new DataStream inside my flatMap function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [side output](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/side_output/), which can't be done if you're using a FlatMap function.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use side output with ProcessFunction to implement